# Can't install m2e-wtp in eclipse indigo (can't connect to mavenarchiver update site)

Tags: eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

does anybody know if there is some other update site for mavenarchiver? I am trying to install m2eclipse-wtp from this update site: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/m2eclipse-wtp/

This is composed of 3 other update sites and one of them is for mavenarchiver (http://repository.tesla.io:8081/nexus/content/sites/m2e.extras/m2eclipse-mavenarchiver/0.15.0/N/0.15.0.201207090125/). I can go to this page via browser, but I can't download any file and can't go to any folder on this site. As well, my eclipse can't connect to this update site. And without maven archiver I can't install m2e-wtp.

I am installing those plugins in my CI server and I haven't problem with that for last 3 months. Since last friday (31.08.2012) I have this problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there was an update based on http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/m2e-wtp-dev/msg00029.html.

The update is out at http://git.eclipse.org/c/m2e-wtp/org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.git/commit/?id=c9da2ffa7ae8e17f7e00a2ecbef01f3871e83cb8

I suspect you may have an issue with the site being blocked.